# javafx 8 - table pagination issue stack overflow

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, javafx-8

This is the layout I want to make

[image]

This is fxml file: category.main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Pagination?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="381.0" prefWidth="899.0" styleClass="background-white" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ciro.hm.controller.CategoryMainController">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="573.0" style="-fx-min-width: 80%;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="321.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
         <children>
            <BorderPane>
               <center>
                  <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="323.0" prefWidth="573.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="colId" editable="false" minWidth="30.0" prefWidth="75.0" resizable="false" styleClass="table-cell" text="%tbl.id" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="colName" editable="false" prefWidth="253.0" resizable="false" styleClass="table-cell" text="%tbl.name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="colInOut" editable="false" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="155.0" styleClass="table-cell" text="%tbl.in.out" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="colBtn" editable="false" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="90.0" resizable="false" sortable="false" styleClass="table-cell" text="#" />
                    </columns>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </TableView>
               </center>
            </BorderPane>
            <Pagination fx:id="pagination" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="573.0" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox layoutX="448.0" maxWidth="203.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
         <children>
            <TitledPane animated="false" collapsible="false" prefHeight="264.0" prefWidth="400.0" text="%app.pane.category">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="201.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="btnSave" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="151.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="%app.lbl.save" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" />
                        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="%app.lbl.name" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="fldInOut" layoutX="17.0" layoutY="101.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="%app.generic.selection" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" />

                              <Label layoutX="71.0" layoutY="80.0" text="%app.lbl.in.out" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" />
                         <TextField fx:id="fldName" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="35.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </TitledPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is controller

```
package com.ciro.hm.controller;

import com.ciro.hm.model.Category;
import com.ciro.hm.service.CategoryService;
import com.ciro.hm.to.CategoryTO;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphsDude;
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class CategoryMainController extends BaseController implements Initializable {

    ObservableList<Category> data;

    @FXML
    BorderPane mainBorder;

    @Value("${app.hm.in-out-value}")
    List<String> inOut;
    @FXML
    TableView<Category> table;
    @FXML
    TextField fldName;
    @FXML
    ComboBox<String> fldInOut;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Category, Integer> colId;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Category, String> colName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Category, String> colInOut;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Category, String> colBtn;

    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Autowired
    public CategoryMainController(CategoryService categoryService){
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        super.initialize(location, resources);

        data = categoryService.findAll();


        fldInOut.getItems().removeAll();
        fldInOut.getItems().addAll(inOut);
        btnSave.setOnAction(this::save);

        pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(0);
        pagination.setPageCount(getPageSize(data));
        pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);

        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(0, paginationSize)));

        colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("idCategory"));
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        colInOut.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("inOut"));
        colBtn.setCellFactory(getEditCellFactory());
    }

    private Callback<TableColumn<Category, String>, TableCell<Category, String>> getEditCellFactory() {
        return  new Callback<TableColumn<Category, String>, TableCell<Category, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Category,String> call(final TableColumn<Category, String> param) {
                return new TableCell<Category, String>() {

                    Button btn = getEditBtn();
                    {
                        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                            Category data = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
                            save(event);
                        });
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setText(null);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(btn);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                };

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Button getEditBtn(){
        Button b = GlyphsDude.createIconButton(FontAwesomeIcon.EDIT,btnEditText,iconSize,fontSize, ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        btnEditCssClass.forEach(s->b.getStyleClass().add(s));
        return  b;
    }



    private void save(ActionEvent event) {

        log.debug(event.toString());
        CategoryTO categoryTO = new CategoryTO(fldName.getText(), (String) fldInOut.getValue());
        categoryService.save(categoryTO);
    }

    private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {

        int fromIndex = pageIndex * paginationSize;
        int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + paginationSize, data.size());
        pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(pageIndex);

        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));
        return mainBorder;
    }
}
```

The first problem is that during the initialization of the controller the createPage method is executed twice. Which seems pretty strange to me. The initialization of the parent class requires only the assignment of the boundle source to a property of the class. The second problem is that at the click of a single page the call to the createPage method goes into a loop generating a stack overflow. As with the guides, the method returns the container in which the table is included. The pagination element is external to it and therefore should not be cyclically reloaded. Some advice?

In any case, the entire application is based on spring boot

EDIT: CHANGE METHOD

I modified this

```
 private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {
        log.info("Page index: " + pageIndex);
        int fromIndex = pageIndex * paginationSize;
        int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + paginationSize, data.size());


        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));
        return table;
    }
```

and it's initialized and execute once ...but layout explode

[image]

Comment: Setting the `currentPageIndex` on the page factory seems wrong. Basically you're modifying a property from a listener to it here. Even if it isn't wrong, there's no need to do this. Remember that this method is called as the result of the modification of the property.

Comment: I removed this `pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(pageIndex);` but method is invoked twice on initialize and 3 times on page click. 
In addition, page 1 remains selected in the paging bar and the label relative to the current page / total pages is not updated

Answer (score 0):

Ok instead of

```
pagination.setPageFactory
```

just use

```
pagination.currentPageIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        createPage(newValue.intValue());
    }

});
```

then change createPage method in this way

```
private void createPage(int pageIndex) {
    log.info("Page index: " + pageIndex);
    int fromIndex = pageIndex * paginationSize;
    int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + paginationSize, data.size());

    table.setMinHeight(400);
    table.getItems().clear();
    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));
}
```

moreover

```
 private void createPage(int pageIndex) {
    int fromIndex = pageIndex * paginationSize;
    int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + paginationSize, data.size());

    table.getItems().clear();
    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));
}
```

moreover borderpane node is not necessary